# C# Websocket.io keeps disconnecting from Socket.io nodejs server

Tags: c#, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Im able to receive emits from my nodejs server using socket.io with the code below.  however, the connection keeps closing.  How do i keep it open forever?

```
      static async Task Main(string[] args) {
           RunSocketClient();
       }    

   public static void RunSocketClient(Host host) {
            String myJson2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(host);

            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:3005/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=websocket");

            ws.OnOpen += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to Socket.IO Server");
            };

            ws.OnClose += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Socket.io Connection closed.");
                while (!ws.IsAlive)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Reconnecting once again...");
                    Task.Delay(10000).Wait();
                    ws.Connect();
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit...");
                    Console.ReadKey(true);
                }
            };

            ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
                ws.SendAsync(myJson2, success =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("sending scuccessful");
                });
            };


            ws.Connect();
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            ws.Close();



        }
```

Comment: does it close immediately? does it close after sending some messages? does it close after some amount of time? or...?

Comment: its actually random, certain times it ends faster then others.  but the most i had it on was for about 60 seconds then it automatically closes.  here with this code its been closing within a few seconds